# servlet application does not work, although tomcat works correctly

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have installed Apache Tomcat on ubuntu under tomcat directory. I set `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable for a single session via export. Then I started tomcat from the command line via `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`. And everything worked well. I saw tomcat official page and assume that the server is installed correctly. Then I created a webb application with a single servlet under

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webaps/apress/
```

directory.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response)
          throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>hello, world</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1> hello world</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Then I compiled the file

```
javac -cp HelloWorldServlet.java -d ./classes -cp $CATALINA_HOME/bin/servlet-api.jar
```

Compillation was successful and the class file was put into the classes subdirectory of the root directory of the application.

Then I edited web.xml file.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns.xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http:/java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Chapter 2</display-name>
    <description> Apress demo</description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then I restartd Tomcat. But when I try to access via

```
http://localhost:8080/apress/hello.html
```

I get Http status 404 message. What I have done wrong?

Comment: Can you type "echo $CATALINA_HOME" and put the result here? Also, can you show us your directory layout under Tomcat and Catalina Home?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you first try building your application in an IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse, then study the configuration files that are automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your tomcat directory there is a logs directory.  Stop tomcat. Delete all the log files and restart tomcat and hit that URL.  Check the logs (mainly access log and catalina.out).  Look for errors in there first.

You may also want to consider using @WebServlet instead of editing the web.xml, modern versions of tomcat can identify classes annotated with this and automatically register them as servlets.

```
@WebServlet(name="HelloWorld", urlPatterns={"/hello.html"})
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

}
```

Also, how are you deploying this servlet, as a WAR file?

Comment: I looked up the directory, there were a bunch of files, I deleted all of them and looked inside catalina.out but understood nothing, but there were mistakes I guess. Can u help me with that?

Comment: Post the contents of the file (it shouldn't be too big since you just restarted it and ran only 1 url).  Also how are you getting your .class file into tomcat?  Are you creating a WAR file or manually copying it to the classes directory?

Comment: SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 19 column 4: The element type "servlet-class" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</servlet-class>".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/apress/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 4; The element type "servlet-class" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</servlet-class>" I edited web.xml but the error kepps appearing

Comment: That error says that web.xml has an XML error.  Go to like 19 column 4, and make sure that open XML tag has a matching and correctly spelled close tag.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible things. According to what you wrote, the directory you created the application was:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webaps/apress/
```

It's supposed to be

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/apress/
```

But i guess it is just a typeO.

the second thing is that you should copy the compiled file

```
HelloWorldServlet.class
```

to

```
apress/WEB-INF/classes
```

directory, or directly compile the java file into this directory

Comment: yeah, u r correct about webapps, and I compiled the .class file into classes directory

Comment: according to what you wrote, you compiled it to /classes under the same directory of HelloWorldServlet.java. As some requested you should post your direcotry structure under CATALINA_HOME